# Convert a line that consists of hex numbers to binary

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a line of `" 39 14 40 00 21 74 D1 69   22 53 AA 36 A4 08 2F 49"`. Each number is a hex value. I want to convert each individual hex number to a binary number. I know python doesn't understand hex values etc. 
Problem i see is this line i am picking form a text file and saving it as a string. Once saved as string python doesn't allow me to convert each individual value to hex.

When i save a given line form a file i save it either as list or string. 
List can't be converted but the i am having trouble converting the string to hex as well. Example i want the first value 39 to be written as 0011 1001 and so on in binary.

```
if line1.startswith("Start Test tb_sctpReadEFuseTest"):
    hex_line = str([next(islice(file_name, 38, 39))[6:55]])
    binary_form= ''.join(['{0:08b}'.format(x) for x in hex_line])
    print(hex_line)
    print(binary_form)
```

String : `39 14 40 00 21 74 D1 69 22 53 AA 36 A4 08 2F 49`
Output : `0011 1001 0001 0100 0100 0000 0000 0000 0010 0001 0111 0100` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format is of no help here as it expects a numerical value not a string.
One way (kind of 'brute force' though) may be to create a dictionary converting each character from '0' to 'F' to their binary representation:

```
hex2bin = { '0': '0000', '1': '0001' ... 'F': '1111'}
```

and use it in your comprehension, that you will have to adapt, for sure, as you will need to parse for each character and skip spaces.
I am sorry, I am really not good at comprehensions and cannot help you more, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression to generate the hex digits, then format as binary like this:

```
>>> s = '39 14 40 00 21 74 D1 69 22 53 AA 36 A4 08 2F 49'
>>> ' '.join('{:0>4b}'.format(int(y, 16)) for x in s.split() for y in x)
'0011 1001 0001 0100 0100 0000 0000 0000 0010 0001 0111 0100 1101 0001 0110 1001 0010 0010 0101 0011 1010 1010 0011 0110 1010 0100 0000 1000 0010 1111 0100 1001'
```

The genexp splits the input string by spaces, then iterates over the characters in each resultant item and formats as the string representation of a four-bit binary number.

Comment: using this method it by default prints or saves the numbers like this "['39 14 40 00 21 74 D1 69   22 53 AA 36 A4 08 2F 49']". There's [' extra which i am not able to get rid of. Because of this, it's making it hard.

Comment: What _exactly_ is the output of `hex_line = str([next(islice(file_name, 38, 39))[6:55]])` ?  It sounds like it is not the same as the string in your question.

Comment: ['39 14 40 00 21 74 D1 69 22 53 AA 36 A4 08 2F 49'] is the output. Sorry i'll update the question as well.

Comment: Making the answer use `s[0].split()` ought t owork.